# Realizar una función con JQuery una vez X etiqueta cambie de nombre de clase

Tags: jquery

Estoy utilizando una libreria llamada **PACE**, que me permite imprimir una barra de progreso del cargado de la página.
Cuando la barra llega al 100%, **PACE** le da una clase al body (*.pace-done*), hasta que no llegue al 100% se llamará *.pace-running*.

¿Hay alguna manera de que cuando la clase del body cambie, que haga un fadeout del div en el que se encuentra la barra y aparezca otro con el contenido principal?

He probado lo siguiente:

```
if($('body').hasClass('pace-done')){
    $('#intro').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.container').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

No funciona. Supongo que porque cuando el archivo **.js** carga, el body aún tiene la clase *.pace-running*...

**P.D.:** Esta es la librería, por si hay algún interesado **[enlace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)**

**Muchas gracias por la ayuda!**

Comment: podrias publicar tu codigo completo porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [documentación de PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/#events) se definen algunos eventos que se pueden controlar a través de la API del plugin (traducción mía):

> Pace fires the following events:
>
> - `start`: cuando se inicia el pace, o como parte de un restart
> - `stop`: cuando el pace se para manualmente, o como parte de un restart
> - `restart`: cuando el pace se reinicia (manualmente o al hacer una nueva llamada AJAX)
> - `done`: cuando el pace termina
> - `hide`: cuando el pace se oculta (puede ser más tarde que `done`, basándose en `ghostTime` y `minTime`)

Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es añadir un controlador del evento `done` que se ejecutará cuando el pace termine, y entonces podrás ocultar/mostrar lo que quieras.

Sería algo como esto (no lo he probado y puede contener fallos):

```
Pace.on("done", function() {
    $('#intro').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.container').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: Ostras es cierto. Muchísimas gracias. Ha funcionado a la perfección!